# Decreasing output of a voltage doubler

Tags: voltage-doubler, power-supply

I'm trying to build the following circuit. The advice on the site I got it from said to try using 1n4001's instead of 1n5817's, because that would get the voltage down to around 15V, which is what I need. Looking at the schematic, though, the 4001's are precisely what are used in the standard doubler design.

What should I do to drop the output to 15V? I'm not much of an electrical engineer. I just follow directions. Thanks for your help.

[image: Bipolar doubler layout]

[image: Bipolar doubler schematic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the formula... +Vout will be

Vin = 9V
VL = 1.1V @ 100ma (Regulator loss)
Vdiode = 1V

+Vout will be 18 - (1.1 + 2) = 14.9
-Vout will be -18 + (1.1 + 2) = -14.9

For smaller (<100ma) loads the VL will be less and the output voltage(s) will be higher.

Keep in mind that this is a voltage doubler, not a regulator. The output will vary according to load and input voltage.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that when I test it with my multimeter, I'm not getting real-world performance? That makes sense. So I should wire it up to the circuit and test it there. Thank you! I'll try that.

Comment: That did the trick. It's now doing 15V and change. Thanks so much!